# setting BOOL in viewcontroller from appdelegate

Tags: iphone, ios5, boolean, uiapplicationdelegate

I've defined a BOOL into my header's AppDelegate.

AppDelegate.h

```
BOOL myBool;

@property(nonatomic) BOOL myBool;
```

and synthesize it

```
@synthesize myBool;
```

How I'm able to set his value (true or false ) from an ViewController ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyAppDelegate* myAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
myAppDelegate.myBool = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

`(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].myBool = YES;`